# Magento 2.3.0 product urls end with .html.html

Tags: magento2, product

I noticed some of my products had an extra .html at the end.

SQL query:

UPDATE url_rewrite SET request_path = REPLACE(request_path, '.html.html', '.html');

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1062 - Duplicate entry 'master-sets.html-1' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID'

Anyone plz help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the underlying cause is - there could be many different ones. However, I can see that you have a duplicate URL key in `master-sets.html` (and potentially others) that are causing errors.

Magento has a clause that you cannot have duplicate URL keys - this is so that one URL (eg: `master-sets.html`) maps distinctly to one action (eg: product page, ID 1234)

Typically, in this case I would do a few things: **NOTE: RUN WITH CAUTION**

**Delete values for the eav_attribute url_path**

`url_path` isn't really used in Magento 2 the same way it's used in Magento 1, and these can cause conflict issues. You can delete these quite easily:

```sql
delete from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = (
    select attribute_id from eav_attribute
    where attribute_code = 'url_path' and entity_type_id = 4
);
```

This query will delete every `url_path` for products (`entity_type_id = 4`) stored in the underlying EAV table.

**Remove product rewrites from the url_rewrite table**

(Make sure you have a backup you can restore to, and you run this on a non-production environment first!)

Typically, you can expect the `url_rewrite` table to be regenerated when you reindex. A reasonably risk-free SQL query to run would be:

```sql
delete from url_rewrite where target_path like 'catalog/product/view/id%' and is_autogenerated = 1;
```

This will delete all the auto-generated url rewrites for products.

At this point, I would suggest reindexing (`bin/magento indexer:reindex`) and seeing if you have these URLs.

If you do, in your example I would pull up the URL keys directly in the database:

```sql
select * from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = (
    select attribute_id from eav_attribute
    where attribute_code = 'url_key' and entity_type_id = 4
) and value like 'master-sets%';
```

This query will grab every URL key that starts with `master-sets` - you may have quite a lot depending on your product set up, but you may also have some duplicates!

What you might see is that multiple products (denoted by the `entity_id` field) have the same `value` field. At this point, you just need to update one of them (in the DB or in the admin panel)

Finally, to see if any products have a URL key that ends in `.html`:

```sql
select cpe.sku, cpe.entity_id, cpev.value from catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev
    join catalog_product_entity cpe on (cpe.entity_id = cpev.entity_id)
    where cpev.value like '%.html';
```

This will output a list of SKUs, their product ID and the erroneous URL key.